# Contains() in visual studio doesnt work

Tags: c#, emgucv

I try to fond out if tow objects - recorded by a Kinec touches or not. For that I define to kinds of shapes (handArea) and (DangerArea). For collision detection I have written the follwing code:

```
private bool checkAreaViolation(List<MCvBox2D> DangerAreas, List<MCvBox2D> HandAreas)
{
    int zaehler;
    int ZaehlerDA;
    int Test;
    String TestS;
    Test = 0;
    ZaehlerDA= 0;
    foreach (MCvBox2D DangerBox in DangerAreas)
    {
        zaehler = 0;
        ZaehlerDA++;
        foreach (MCvBox2D HandBox in HandAreas)
        {   
            if(zaehler<=HandAreas.Count-1)
                if (DangerAreas.Contains(HandAreas[zaehler])==true)
                    return true;

            PointF[] handVertices = HandBox.GetVertices();
            for (int i = 0; i < handVertices.Length; i++)
            {
                if (PointInPolygon(handVertices[i], DangerBox.GetVertices()))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                zaehler++; 
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

unfortunately the `if (DangerAreas.Contains(HandAreas[zaehler])==true)` doesn't work at all.

Does anybody knows why?

Comment: This looks like C# rather than C++. You are using a wrong tag.

Comment: I'm not too good with C#, but .Contains in VB is normally for Strings, not sure if it's the same in C#, and also, check if 'DangerArea' != Nothing.

Answer (score 1):

`System.Collections.Generic.List<t>.Contains` checks if and only if the list contains that **exact** element. This is almost never going to happen in practice. It looks like you really want to check the areas for either intersection or inclusion instead. (You can do this with a simple Linq query)

Answer (score 1):

You should implement IEquatable interface and overload Equals(T other) method, so now compiler knows which field must be compared when doing Contains() method.

```
public class MCvBox2D:IEquatable<MCvBox2D>
    {
    ..............

    private override bool Equals(MCvBox2D other)
    {
       if(this.fieldName==other.fieldName)
          return true;
    }

    ..............
    }
```

**note:** replace fieldName with field you want to be compared by

Answer (score 0):

Try `.Any()` with Linq and you can use any expression to find out if it contains some object with certain property.